# SQL como fazer select em 2 colunas diferentes

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query

Estou tentando fazer um `SELECT` para selecionar 2 colunas diferentes da mesma tabela, exemplo:

```
   id   |   name   |      tags
-----------------------------------
    1   |   acao   |      null
    2   | aventura |      null
    3   |   rpg    |  acao,aventura
```

Tentei de diversas formas fazer este `SELECT` mas não consegui que funcionasse:

```
SELECT * FROM jogos WHERE
name LIKE "%acao%",
tags LIKE "%acao%"
```

Quero que quando pesquisado "acao" retorne desta forma:

```
   id   |   name   |       tags
-----------------------------------
    1   |   acao   |       null
    3   |   rpg    |  acao,aventura
```

Não tenho mais nenhuma ideia de como fazer isso funcionar.

Comment: Não falta o operador OR, não? SELECT * FROM jogos WHERE
name LIKE "%acao%" OR tags LIKE "%acao%"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para juntar instruções na cláusula `WHERE` você deve usar a palavra `AND`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM jogos
 WHERE name LIKE "%acao%"
   AND tags LIKE "%acao%"
```

Caso queira testar a busca em qualquer uma das colunas, independente do valor da outra, utilize a palavra `OR`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM jogos
 WHERE name LIKE "%acao%"
    OR tags LIKE "%acao%"
```

Comment: Usando desta forma ele não me retorna nada de nenhum dos campos, usando `AND` a linha precisa ter "acao" tanto no campo name como no tag para retornar algo. Usando "OR" funcionou, não acredito que esqueci disso hahahahh

Comment: Veja com o `OR`